# Adding a List/GridView to a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, gridview, fragment

I've got an Application which is basically just a gridview, you click on one of the grids and it loads up a message.

I'm looking to update the Application. I want to add a Menu and also change it to Fragments (One for Menu (ListView) and one for Content (ListView or GridView depending on what menu option is selected)).

Is it be possible to keep my current GridView code and Create new Classes for the Menu / Main (including their layouts) and then using my current GridView code to the populate the Content part upon clicking on the relevant menu option?﻿

I've looked at a few tutorials but i'm not having much luck putting it together so far.  I'm not so much looking to be told what to do, just looking for some advice and help (links etc) so I can get learning and get my app updated

Answer (score 1):

It is possible .and it is not too hard .Same thing i have done this before . first you will create a Java class and xml file in your project package . Hear is an example , i consider `Thana` is your java class and `activity_tha` is xml file .

```
public class Thana extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{
// your global variable goes hear.

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState)         
    {    
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tha, container, false);

    // put you all code from old Activity class's onCreate() method .
    // be careful this Fragmetn's onCreateView () returns a view object so look this

    TextView headingThana = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.heading_thana); 
    // you always need a view reference to making any object of Widget from xml file.

    return rootView;
}
// and other code goes hear as like as your old class
```

}

Hear is another **important point**, you will not able to get your application reference to use  from `Context context;` or `this` so you need replace them all by `getActivity()` method . 
like this

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(this, thanaInfoList, thanaMobileNumber));
```

`this` replaced by `getActivity();`

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), thanaInfoList, thanaMobileNumber));
```

for menu item you need a xml file in res/menu folder. like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_searchss" 
    android:title="action_searcheee" 
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    >

</item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_search" 
    android:title="action_search" 
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    >

</item>
```

and now write this `inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);` in your `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method . `activity_main_actions` is your newly created xml file in menu folder .......... for menu selection you can override this method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // your code goes hear may be you can use swith case  . its better 
}
```

this is just an Idea not exact answer . thank you